# How to remove proximity alerts?

Tags: android, proximity

I have the following

```
locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude,
                    longitude,
                    radius,
                    -1,
                    pendingIntent);
```

How can I remove the proximity alert?

Now, you may say "use removeProximityAlert", but to do that I think I need the pending intent with which the alert was created. If the activity stays on the forefront and is never destroyed I can do that easily but what if the activity is destroyed?

The situation is the following: I have my app, set the latitude and longitude I want, then add a proximity alert. Then the train I am in moves or I have to give my seat to an elderly lady and the tablet gets moved changing orientation- this makes the activity gets destroyed and created again -  Now I want to remove the alert. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Call `locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent)` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeProximityAlert(android.app.PendingIntent))

The pending intent should be created in the same way with the same extras as the pending intent used to call `locationManager.addProximityAlert(...)`